# Eclipse Debugger Icons

Tags: java, eclipse, icons

I'm looking for a way to be able to find the icons used by the Eclipse Java Debugger (in particular like the icons that are used in the variable debugging view). Does any one know where the icons are located in the eclipse folders, or whether there is some kind of easy way eclipse has provided a developer to allow them easy access to those icons (for example I can easily import ISharedImages for those particular icons)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an online [resource](http://eclipse-icons.i24.cc/):

Additional, ctrl+f for "Reuse" at the [official site](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-UI-Guidelines/Index.html):

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try directly from the source repo

http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.debug.ui/icons/